# Energy flux proportionality

Tags: classical-mechanics, optics, waves

It is considered trivial in texts that if:

$J \propto \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}$

Where $J$ is the energy flux, then $J$ is proportional to the amplitude of the wave squared. Why? What is the logical step to go from the first to the latter? We have proportionality between the derivatives, I fail to see how that means the amplitude squared...

Comment: hint $\psi \propto Acos(kx-\omega t + \phi_0)$

Comment: Simpler than I though, thank you.